# What version of Debian is my Kali Linux based on?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, version

I am trying to download Virtualbox on my Kali Linux and I would like know which Debian my Kali Linux is based off of. I'm not finding `uname -a` or `cat /etc/*-release` useful in this pursuit. I'm trying to install a version of Oracle's VirtualBox which only ships for specific Debian releases. Which one should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/714874/how-can-i-find-out-what-distro-i-am-running

Comment: cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Kali
DISTRIB_RELEASE=2.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux 2.0"
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux 2.0 (sana)"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2.0 (sana)"
VERSION_ID="2.0"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kali.org/"

Comment: Consider choosing this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/660343/3285

Answer (score 3):

Most of the command above reflect Kali attributes,to get the original forked debian distribution you may use :

```
cat /proc/version
```

Will show Kali along with forked debian

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Kali and Debian

Kali has detailed this in their blog post [*"Kali's Relationship With Debian"*](https://www.kali.org/docs/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian/).

> The Kali Linux distribution is based on **Debian Testing**. Therefore, most of the Kali packages are imported, as-is, from the Debian repositories. In some cases, newer packages may be imported from Debian Unstable or Debian Experimental, either to improve user experience, or to incorporate needed bug fixes.

[Debian Testing is a rolling development release.](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting)

> Debian testing is the **current development state of the next stable Debian distribution.** It is also made available under the code name of the next stable release, Bullseye is the current testing codename.

So in short, they're *not* based on A Debian Release. Like Ubuntu and many others, Kali does source their packages from Debian.

### Don't create a FrankenDebian

What you're wanting to do is what we call making a ["FrankenDebian"](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). Because Debian Testing is rolling any version of it will be different from any released or frozen version of Debian. So the question amounts to more or less,

> At the time I'm doing this what release of Debian is closest to the release that Kali took when they froze Debian Testing.

That's going to be very contemporary,

- if Kali sourced testing *after* Debian froze testing and made a release then Kali may have a newer version than any released version of Debian.
- if Kali sourced testing *before* Debian froze testing and made a release then they're going to likely have an older version of said things.

**This is will not be good for you either way.**

### A way out with Containers

A better idea is to simply use Debian Stable (which Oracle supports) and run Kali in a container. You can [find information on the Kali site about using their Docker or LXC/LXD images](https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/).

Answer (score 1):

Per Kali Linux [release notes](https://www.kali.org/releases/kali-linux-20-released/):

> **So, what’s new in Kali 2.0?** There’s a new 4.0 kernel, now based on Debian Jessie

Answer (score 1):

From [Kali Linux Official Documentation:](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian)

> The Kali Linux distribution is based on Debian Wheezy.

But, as noted, Kali 2.0's new 4.0 kernel is based on Debian Jessie.

From your results of `uname -a`, you have `Kali Linux 2.0` with a kernel version of `4.0.0`, hence your kali is based on Debian Jessie.

Comment: Where can I look this up ? thank you btw fast replay

Comment: No problem. You can follow the links provided on this page for more information. In particular, you can look at [kali linux 2.0 released](https://www.kali.org/releases/kali-linux-20-released/) for Kali 2.0, which is what you have.

Answer (score -2):

Many distros support the Linux Standard Base conformant distros support the [lsb_release](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html) command:

```
lsb_release --codename
```

Even without the `lsb_command` one can often find

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

and grepping for `VERSION`.

Comment: As per the updated question, this only reveals the Kali version, and not which Debian release it's based on.